# Migrating Hibernate .hbm to annotations

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am currently migrating an older application from hbm mappings to annotations. I have read numerous places stating that it is possible to do this, including the hibernate docs. I am running into trouble when I try to reference an annotated class from an hbm mapped with a many-to-one relationship.

I am getting the following error complaining about the annotated class.

"nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: ...cepis.domain.Note"

Is it possible to achieve what I want here, is there something very basic that I am missing (note like I said I have read numerous times that it is possible so a simple "yes it is possible" will not be of much help)?

My session factory is defined as follows ...

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
    scope="singleton">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="itc5DataSource" />             
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
              <value>edu/uky/cepis/User.hbm.xml</value>...  
        </list>     
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>edu.uky.cepis.domain.Note</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${itc5.dialect}</prop>
            ...
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Thank you so much for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried setting _ hibernate.mapping.precedence_ to "class, hbm"?

Comment: Yes I hav.... I added this to my Session factory like so .... <bean id="sessionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
  scope="singleton">
  <property name="hibernate.mapping.precedence" value="class, hbm" />